# Is there a way with a SP Calculated field to count number of "Yes" answers?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-2013

I have twenty six fields/columns in a SharePoint list called F01 - F26 that are simple drop down fields that can be either Yes or No.  I am trying to programmatically count how many times F01 - F26 are set to Yes using a Calculated field.

In the past I used the following to count how many of the twenty six fields were not blank:

```
=COUNTA(F01,F02,F03,F04,F05,F06,F07,F08,F09,F10,F11,F12,F13,F14,F15,F16,F17,F18,F19,F20,F21,F22,F23,F24,F25,F26)
```

I tried this but it failed

```
IF([F01] = "YES", 1, 0)+ IF([F02] = "YES", 1, 0)+ IF([F03] = "YES", 1, 0)+ IF([F04] = "YES", 1, 0)+ IF([F05] = "YES", 1, 0)+ IF([F06] = "YES", 1, 0)+ IF([F07] = "YES", 1, 0)+ IF([F08] = "YES", 1, 0)+ IF([F09] = "YES", 1, 0)+ IF([F10] = "YES", 1, 0)+ IF([F11] = "YES", 1, 0)+ IF([F12] = "YES", 1, 0)+ IF([F13] = "YES", 1, 0)+ IF([F14] = "YES", 1, 0)+ IF([F15] = "YES", 1, 0)+ IF([F16] = "YES", 1, 0)+ IF([F17] = "YES", 1, 0)+ IF([F18] = "YES", 1, 0)+ IF([F19] = "YES", 1, 0)+ IF([F20] = "YES", 1, 0)+ IF([F21] = "YES", 1, 0)+ IF([F22] = "YES", 1, 0)+ IF([F23] = "YES", 1, 0)+ IF([F24] = "YES", 1, 0)+ IF([F25] = "YES", 1, 0)+ IF([F26] = "YES", 1, 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

If they are Yes/No columns, then they can be just treated as zeros and ones.

```
= F01 + F02 + F03 + F04 + ...
```

You did not say what the error was, but if you are using a choice column, and using "Yes" and "No" values, and the error was from the length of the formula, try this one:

```
=(F01="Yes")+(f02="Yes")+(f03="Yes") ...
```

Each Boolean that's "true" is treated as a 1.

Comment: thanks.... that worked... where can I find documented the limitations on calculated fields?

Comment: I don't know of a single official list. Here's one I found: https://spandcrm.com/2016/11/09/sharepoint-calculated-column-and-nested-ifs-limitation-cheat-sheet/

Answer (score 0):

The formula below works for me.

```
IF([F01] = "YES", 1, 0)+ IF([F02] = "YES", 1, 0)+ IF([F03] = "YES", 1, 0)+ IF([F04] = "YES", 1, 0)+ IF([F05] = "YES", 1, 0)+ IF([F06] = "YES", 1, 0)+ IF([F07] = "YES", 1, 0)+ IF([F08] = "YES", 1, 0)+ IF([F09] = "YES", 1, 0)+ IF([F10] = "YES", 1, 0)+ IF([F11] = "YES", 1, 0)+ IF([F12] = "YES", 1, 0)+ IF([F13] = "YES", 1, 0)+ IF([F14] = "YES", 1, 0)+ IF([F15] = "YES", 1, 0)+ IF([F16] = "YES", 1, 0)+ IF([F17] = "YES", 1, 0)+ IF([F18] = "YES", 1, 0)+ IF([F19] = "YES", 1, 0)+ IF([F20] = "YES", 1, 0)+ IF([F21] = "YES", 1, 0)+ IF([F22] = "YES", 1, 0)+ IF([F23] = "YES", 1, 0)+ IF([F24] = "YES", 1, 0)+ IF([F25] = "YES", 1, 0)+ IF([F26] = "YES", 1, 0)
```

[image]
I suggest you provide the error message for further research.